# More efficient way of indicating whether message is read or not?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, notifications

Okay.  I have this working fine in an asynctask but there's got to be a less cumbersome way of doing it.

In my app I have a "News" bar that will show a "!" if the message has not been read or is new.  If it has been read there will be no "!" until a new message arrives.

How I accomplish this is I download and parse a JSON file at regular intervals.  I convert the message to a hash code and compare the value to a hash code already saved in a file of the previous message downloaded.  Additionally I have another "ReadStatus" file with a "read" or "unread" value written to it.

When the user clicks the "News" bar to read the message it rewrites the "ReadStatus" file with a "read" value.  Whenever the asynctask downloads and parses the JSON data and coverts it to a hash code, if the hash code doesn't match the saved hash code value or if it does match but the value of the "ReadStatus" file is "unread" the "!" appears.  Also, in the event of non-matching hash codes, not only does it trigger the "!" but also rewrites the "ReadStatus" file with an "unread" value.

This whole process seems overly laborious though but I'm having a tough time figuring out a more efficient, less code-intensive way of accomplishing the same result.  Anyone with considerably more experience have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a database?  Store the readstatus in the database.

Comment: I guess I don't really see the point of a hash code.  I would just use a read/unread status value.

Comment: The hash code isn't for the read/unread status value.  It's for checking if the message downloaded is the same as the one before or new.  I thought it would be less memory and easier to check hash codes against each other instead of strings of characters. @EvanStoddard